# WQL syntax: DiskDriveToDiskPartition with a LIKE operator

Tags: c#, syntax, wql

So I'm trying to match up physical drives to partitions to drive letters, and DiskDriveToDiskPartition seems like a good candidate for doing that, but I'm struggling to get the query to work like I want it to:

I've used the WMI Query Builder to create the gist of the query:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition WHERE 
    Antecedent = \\\\localhost\\root\\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\\\\\.\\\\PHYSICALDRIVE3"");
```

For starters, Visual Studio tells me that this isn't a valid query as it has too many \ characters in it, plus there are illegal quotes that need to be sorted. Secondly, I'd like to simply the WHERE clause to just read

```
WHERE Antecedent LIKE \"%" + physicalDriveID + "%\"
```

The idea being to pass it a PHYSICALDRIVE variable, but all I get is Invalid Query errors.

Any pointers in the right direction on this one?

Either getting the WMI Query Builder to run or getting my LIKE clause to run would be really helpful!

Comment: did you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

An answer is probably a long time coming but for the benefit of anyone still interested this was the solution I came up with. The trick is to make use of the *ASSOCIATORS OF* syntax of the WMI query. This way we can effectively JOIN the DeviceID to partitions.

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive"))
{
    // extract model and interface information
    foreach (ManagementObject drive in search.Get())
    {
        string antecedent = drive["DeviceID"].ToString(); // the disk we're trying to find out about
        antecedent = antecedent.Replace(@"\", "\\"); // this is just to escape the slashes
        string query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + antecedent + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher partitionSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject part in partitionSearch.Get())
            {
                //...pull out the partition information
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your example code. It helped me a lot to understand WQL ASSOCIATORS OF. Event if your post is from some time in the past now I'd lke to suggest to remove the antecedent.Replace call because it replaces a backslash with anothe backslash. ;-)

Comment: @Valvestino: it replaces one backslash with 2 backslashes.

Comment: @Thomas: I am sure this would be the intended goal. In fact, the second literal misses either a @ in front of or \\ between the quotes. :-)