# How to get Logical Disk for a specific Hard Disk using WMI?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I am currently working on a project where I need to use WMI (Windows Management Interface). I need to find the Hard Disks, and Logical Disks and some information about them. For example I use the following code to get the physical disk:

```
hd = new HardDrive();
mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '"
                                        + disksModel[i] + "'");
foreach(ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
{
    string vari = moDisk["DeviceID"].ToString();
    hd.HardDiskModel = moDisk["Model"].ToString();
    hd.HardDiskType = moDisk["InterfaceType"].ToString();
    hd.HardDiskStatus = moDisk.Properties["Status"].Value.ToString();
    hd.HardDiskSize = moDisk.Properties["Size"].Value.ToString();
    hd.HardDiskName = moDisk.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
    hd.HardDiskSerialNo = moDisk.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value.ToString();
}
```

And then another query to get logical disks.

**The only thing I'd like to know is**: how can I make sure that I get the logical disks for a specific Hard Disk?

For example, if I have 3 Hard Disks(HD1, HD2, HD3), and 8 logical disks (`c:` to `j:`), how can I make sure in the code that for example `c:` and `d:` belong to HD1, `e:`, `f:`, `g:` and `h:` belong to HD2 and `i:` and `j:` belong to HD3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correlate the `Win32_DiskDrive` with the logical drives using the `ASSOCIATORS OF` sentence, these are the classes which you must use.

- Win32_DiskDrive
- Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
- Win32_DiskPartition
- Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
- Win32_LogicalDisk

Some time ago I wrote a [Delphi sample about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653205/how-can-i-get-the-drive-letter-of-an-usb-device) which you can check, Also you can found a C# sample on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025984/wql-syntax-diskdrivetodiskpartition-with-a-like-operator).